# 1004 error for using usedrange

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy over values from one workbook to another using the usedrange function (there are some blanks in certain rows and it is fine to copy over the blank as well), but I am getting the 1004 error:

```
Sub ActiveInactiveVendors()
Dim ActiveWkb As Workbook, Wkb As Workbook, InactiveWkb As Workbook
Dim ActiveWkst As Worksheet, Wkst As Worksheet, InactiveWkst As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range
Dim targetRng As Range


Set ActiveWkb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\clara\Desktop\active vendors.xlsx")
Set Wkb = ThisWorkbook
Set Wkst = Wkb.Sheets("Vendors")
Set ActiveWkst = ActiveWkb.Worksheets("aqlc7da48e7")

'set column A starting from A7
Set targetRng = Wkst.Range("A7" & Wkst.Rows.Count)
'get the values starting from a32 to the last row used and set it in wkst
targetRng.Value = ActiveWkst.Range("A32"  & ActiveWkst.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Value
End Sub
```

I appreciate any feedback! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
Set targetRng = Wkst.Range("A7" & Wkst.Rows.Count)
```

is not correct.  You are not getting A7:A1048576 but a concatenating of the two.  So it is looking for A71048576 which does not exist

Then you should use similar sized ranges when setting values.

```
Sub ActiveInactiveVendors()
Dim ActiveWkb As Workbook, Wkb As Workbook, InactiveWkb As Workbook
Dim ActiveWkst As Worksheet, Wkst As Worksheet, InactiveWkst As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range
Dim targetRng As Range, origRng As Range


Set ActiveWkb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\clara\Desktop\active vendors.xlsx")
Set Wkb = ThisWorkbook
Set Wkst = Wkb.Sheets("Vendors")
Set ActiveWkst = ActiveWkb.Worksheets("aqlc7da48e7")

'set column A starting from A7
Set origRng = ActiveWkst.Range("A32", ActiveWkst.Cells(ActiveWkst.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
Set targetRng = Wkst.Range("A7", Wkst.Cells(origRng.Rows.Count + 6, 1))
'get the values starting from a32 to the last row used and set it in wkst
targetRng.Value = origRng.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you - the code is finally running and it copied over all the cells in column A of activewkst to wkst but following the last cell copied over, there is a cell that says #NA; also 1000 cells down in wkst it copied over the exact same cells and also the information from column b. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: No it should not do that.  Try clearing the sheet and try the code again.  I did adjust the code above to deal with the `N/A`  Then check your data in the original sheet to ensure it does not duplicate.

Comment: You're right - I just had to clear the sheet again. Silly me! Im just curious as to how changing the +7 to +6 cleared the #NA? Also, If I wanted to copy over cells from another worksheet starting from where targetRng left off, how would I go about this?

Comment: Set origRng = InactiveWkst.Range("A23", InactiveWkst.Cells(InactiveWkst.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
Set targetRng = Wkst.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
targetRng.Value = origRng.Value was what I was thinking

Comment: The target range was one cell too big, so by changing the size it got rid of the N/A.  The second question is a new question an should get a new post, but do some research on how to find the last cell with data.